# Enable/disable one formControl on the basis of another

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to enable disable one formControl on the basis of another, how to achieve that?

I have tried using .enable() and .disable functions on my formControls by default and is not working. Would like some suggestions on how to proceed, below are the specifics

```js
const numberOfQuestionsRequired = this.securityQuestionSetup.get('numberOfQuestionsRequiredToSetupProfile')?.value;

if (numberOfQuestionsRequired != null && numberOfQuestionsRequired !== '') {
  const controlsToDisable = ['numberOfCharToSaveAnswer', 'questionsRequiredForVerification', 'incorrectAttemptsBeforeAccountLockout'];

  controlsToDisable.forEach(controlName => {
    this.securityQuestionSetup.get(controlName)?.disable();
  });
} else {
  const controlsToEnable = ['numberOfCharToSaveAnswer', 'questionsRequiredForVerification', 'incorrectAttemptsBeforeAccountLockout'];

  controlsToEnable.forEach(controlName => {
    this.securityQuestionSetup.get(controlName)?.enable();
  });
}
```

and then called this method in ngOnInit()

Comment: Please note that a long line of code is not a good question title

Comment: You should call to your function not only in onInit else when you change the input "numberOfQuestionsRequiredToSetupProfile"